# What was the role of Karna's kundal?

Tags: mahabharata, karna, surya

We all know that Karna was given a **Kavach and kundal** by his father **Lord Sun**. **Kavach** was for his protection. But what was the role of **Kundal**?

Comment: A "mahabharata" tag is already existing. So a new tag "mahabharat" isn't needed.

Comment: @Rickcross sorry for my mistake

Comment: No need to be sorry. I was just informing you why I removed the tag you have added.

Comment: @sv. absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karna's kundalas (ear rings), along with his kavacha (mail/armour), make him immortal. His ear-rings arose from amrita. It is due to both that Karna cannot be killed in battle.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03308.htm

> Vaisampayana continued, "Although thus urged with various words by Karna, still, O chief of the Bharata race, that Brahmana did not ask for any other boon. And although Karna sought to pacify him to the best of his power, and worshipped him duly, yet that best of Brahmanas did not ask for any other boon. And when that foremost of Brahmanas did not ask for any other boon, Radha's son again spake unto him with a smile, **'My mail, O regenerate one, hath been born with my body, and this pair of ear-rings hath arisen from Amrita. It is for these that I am unslayable in the worlds.**